# How to return the parents of a child in a self referenced table?

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I built this Model to manage content for my website.  It seems to work great except that I can't figure out how to show that "parents" of a given "child".

#### Data Structure

That allows me to organize content into tree.

```
Parent
--- child 1
--- child 2
--- child 3
--------grandchild 1
--------grandchild 2
```

#### MODEL

```
class Service(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('service.id'))
    parent = db.relationship('Service', remote_side=[id], backref='children')
    slug = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)
    label = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    body = db.Column(db.UnicodeText)
    meta_desc = db.Column(db.UnicodeText)
    meta_kw = db.Column(db.UnicodeText)
    date_create = db.Column(db.DateTime)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.slug

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.label
```

This works.....

```
>>> Service.query.filter_by(slug="/about").all()
[About]
```

so does this...

```
>>> Service.query.filter_by(parent=None).all()
[]
```

This doesn't work

```
>>> Service.query.filter_by(parent="/about").all()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/jwogrady/.virtualenvs/medcol/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 1296, in filter_by
    for key, value in kwargs.items()]
  File "/Users/jwogrady/.virtualenvs/medcol/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/operators.py", line 298, in __eq__
    return self.operate(eq, other)
  File "/Users/jwogrady/.virtualenvs/medcol/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 176, in operate
    return op(self.comparator, *other, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jwogrady/.virtualenvs/medcol/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/relationships.py", line 1002, in __eq__
    other, adapt_source=self.adapter))
  File "/Users/jwogrady/.virtualenvs/medcol/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/relationships.py", line 1338, in _optimized_compare
    value = attributes.instance_state(value)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state'
```

For a given child, how do I get the parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all the Services that have a parent with the slug "about", use the [`has`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/internals.html#sqlalchemy.orm.properties.RelationshipProperty.Comparator.has) comparison:

```
Service.query.filter(Service.parent.has(Service.slug == '/about')).all()
```

Or, for better performance on very large tables, use an alias and a join:

```
parent = db.aliased(Service)
Service.query.join((parent, parent.id == Service.parent_id)).filter(parent.slug == '/about').all()
```

---

If you literally mean "how do I get the parent Service of a given Service", you just access it from the instance with `s.parent`.